# Menubar should display only when screen resolution is 800x400 in html,css

Tags: html, css, web

I have a menu bar in html page, it should display only if the
screen resolution is 800x400px. how to achieve this using css3/css only not by using javascript.

Comment: what is your HTML/CSS, can you post it here? and you mean that it should display oinly if the screen is widder or smaller than 800/400px?

Comment: Google for "media queries". It would have taken you less time to find this yourself instead of being lazy and asking someone to do your research for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should keep the menu bar `display:none` and then something like this

```
@media all and (width: 800px) and (height: 400px) {
  #menubar  {
    display:block;
  }
}
```